# Customising Product review block/tab Text string in magento 1.9

Tags: review

Within Magento product review tab. 
I have searched for the source code file of following string: **"You're reviewing: "** to write something else than this. Been looking in several files but not able to find it.

In files like:
`/app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/review/product_review_info.phtml`

 
and 
`/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Form.php`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The following is true for Magento 1.9**

The base file can be found at: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtml`

And the rwd file can be found at: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/review/form.phtml`

Of course this may change based on Magento version and theme installation.